# Calling id of button to javascript file after onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created several buttons using this general code:

```
   <button class="button" id = "b1" value="0" onclick="checker()"></button>
```

I am currently writing a javascript 'checker()' method which checks to see if the 'id' of a button matches an external value. To do this, I need the 'id' of the button to be sent to my script once it's corresponding button clicked. Then, I will set that 'id' variable to a value. How can I do this? I could do it for a button where I know the id, but I want my code to be general. I am open to using jQuery.

Comment: what you would like to do with id when you pass it to a script method? what does men I will set that id variable to a value?

Comment: I am literally going to say var xyz = [value of 'id']

Comment: check for my answer mate

Comment: I guess you want something like this? function checker() { var myId = $(this).attr("id"); //This will retreive clicked button's id. Then compare it with external value, for example, if (myId == targetId) { // Do something } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's create javascript method that will accept id as a parameter:

```
var checker = function(id)
{
  //we will do something here later, lets understand this now
}
```

> I need the 'id' of the button to be sent to my script once it's
>   corresponding button clicked.

So if you want to get the ID of the element the event handler is bound to, you can do this easily with  `this.id` (`this` refers to the element), like this:

```
<button class="button" id = "b1" value="0" onclick="checker(this.id)"></button>
```

> Then, I will set that 'id' variable to a value. How can I do this? I
>   am open to using jQuery.

You could do this by following code below, basically we get the `id` of the clicked button, and inside of your method you could do whatever you want with your `id`. By reading your comment I saw that you would simply assign the value of `id` to some `xyz` variable:

```
var checker = function(id)
{
   var xyz = id; // now your xyz has a value of clicked button id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to using jQuery *and* want to keep your code general, there is a much simpler way to accomplish what you want, with less typing.

**Your Button**

```
<button class="button" id = "b1" value="0"></button>
```

**Your JavaScript**

```
//be sure to include jQuery
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text\javascript">
    //you must call this for jQuery to load/function
    $(function(){
         //anything that has a class of "button", attach this handler
         //this handles any "click" of a button with class "button"
         $(".button").on("click", function(){
               //alert the attribute of id for whatever element (this) was 
               //clicked
               alert($(this).attr("id"));
         });
    });
</script>
```

Below is a working example snippet

```js
$(function(){
    $(".button").on("click", function(){
         var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
         alert(btnId);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" id="b1" value="B1">B1</button>
<button class="button" id="b2" value="B2">B2</button>
```

Comment: Any particular reason one felt they should downvote this answer?  Can it be improved somehow?